# Android Bitmap FileNotFoundException ENOENT while method is only called if file exists

Tags: android, bitmap, filenotfoundexception

I'm tring to load a .png file from my DCIM Folder but it throws the Execption

```
06-25 14:03:09.350: E/BitmapFactory(12552): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android.graphics.Bitmap@421569f8: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have these Permissions added in my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I call this Method to load the File:

```
public static Bitmap getPreview(File parentDir){
    Bitmap toReturn=null;
    File file = new File(parentDir,"preview.png");

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        toReturn=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }
    return toReturn;

}
```

The file does exist and when i display the full path it's

```
06-25 14:03:09.100: I/(12552): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/TextureVisualiser/SetA/preview.png
```

I know I can load Textfiles from this path:

```
06-25 14:03:09.110: I/(12552): /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/TextureVisualiser/SetA/info.txt
```

for the txt file i got the Method:

```
public static String[] readTitleAndSubtitle(File parentDir){
    String[] toReturn = new String[2];
    File file = new File(parentDir,"info.txt");
    Log.i("",""+file);
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        toReturn[0]=br.readLine();
        toReturn[1]=br.readLine();
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

So basicly I have a .txt file and a .png file in the Folder and only the txt file is possible to load. The png file throws the exception.

Edit:
I tried to move it to an other lokation but still I can't read the .png file but I can read the .txt file.

Thx in advance,

Lightbringa

Comment: why You are creating a new directory with if (file.exists()) {       file.getParentFile().mkdirs(); ?

Comment: There is no such android permission as `android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE`, or `android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: I tried it without the mkdirs() but it doesnt change a thing. And earlier I saw a suggestion which told me I should try it.

Comment: Without the wrong permission there is still no change :(

Comment: By the way, and of the BitmapFactory decoding functions, **none of them throws FileNotFoundException**.

Comment: well then how does it get thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I used this stuff for a ListView where I tried to grap the wanted View via

```
    View v = dataAdapter.getView(0,null,null);
    ImageView iv =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Image);
    iv.setImageBitmap(DataHelper.getPreview(allDirects.get(0)));
```

But it doesnt work like this :D

So i build my own BaseAdapter. For all of those who wonder how I did it here is the full Class:

```
package de.bachelorarbeit.main;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import de.bachelorarbeit.R;
import de.bachelorarbeit.helper.DataHelper;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Activity context;
    private final List<File> allDirects;

    public CustomList(Activity context,List<File> allDirects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.allDirects=allDirects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, true);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
    TextView subTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.SubTitle);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.Image);


    String[] both = DataHelper.readTitleAndSubtitle(allDirects.get(position));      
    txtTitle.setText(both[0]);
    subTitle.setText(both[1]);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(DataHelper.getPreview(allDirects.get(position)));
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return allDirects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

Thanks for every help I got,
Lightbringa

Answer (score -1):

Change To This :

```
 if (!file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    }


toReturn=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: didnt change a thing  :(